# unable to load data in django models form a json file

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-database

I am trying to upload JSON file data in my model using pandas but it is causing an error in loading the data

here is my model in which i want to load data

```
class Jsondata(models.Model):
    region =  models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    start_year =  models.IntegerField()
    published = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    
    def __str_(self):
        return self.country
```

here is my load_data.py file

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from users.models import Jsondata

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Load data from JSON file using pandas'

def add_arguments(self, parser):
    parser.add_argument('json_file', type=str)

def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
    json_file_path = kwargs['json_file']

    with open(json_file_path, 'r') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
    
    # Create a DataFrame from JSON data
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    
    # Iterate through DataFrame rows and populate the database
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        item = Jsondata(
                region=row['region'],
                start_year=row['start_year'],
                published=row['published'],
                country=row['country'],

        )
        item.save()
        
    self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS('Data loaded successfully'))
```

and i tried this command to load data in my data

```
python manage.py load_data media\json_files\jsondata.json
```

and my json file look like

```
       {
            "region": "Central America",
            "start_year": "",
            "published": "January, 18 2017 00:00:00",
            "country": "Mexico",
        },
```

any other method to achieve so will also be helpful

Comment: Can you add error traceback?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should fix your JSON because it has a trailing comma and JSON does not allow trailing commas. It should be looking like this:

```
{
    "region": "Central America",
    "start_year": "",
    "published": "January, 18 2017 00:00:00",
    "country": "Mexico"
}
```

---

Second, you need to ensure that your `published` field is being parsed as a datetime object.

Modify your code like this:

`df['published'] = pd.to_datetime(df['published'])`

---

Third, you should allow blank values for the `start_year` field in your model

Modify your code like this:

`start_year = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)`

---

You can also use the built-in `loaddata` command to load the JSON directly into the database without using pandas. This will use **Django's serializer** to load the data into your model.

Make sure that your JSON file is located in a location that Django can find and you would also have to remove the trailing commas from your JSON.

This is what I can offer you since you did not provide the exact error that you have been facing.

Comment: when i tried python manage.py loaddata media\json_files\jsondata.json  django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture 'C:\Users\mithlesh\blackcloffer_assignment\data_dash\media\json_files\jsondata.json':

Comment: it throws the above error

Comment: did you fix your Json?

Comment: yes now it does not have any tailing commas